# JSON.parse fails in function, works in console

Tags: javascript, json

I have a simple script that does a cross site request and gets data from a GitHub gist. The data from the Github API is returned as a JSON string. To allow further modification of the data, I want it as a JSON object.

```
// Create the XHR object.
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

var tmpJSON = "";
var gistData = "";

var gistID = "5789756";
var gitAPI = "https://api.github.com/gists/"
var gistQuery = gitAPI + gistID;

function incrementGist() {
    gistData = createCORSRequest('GET', gistQuery);
    gistData.send();
    tmpJSON = JSON.parse(gistData.response);
}
```

In the html page, I have

```
<p><input type="button" value="Increment" OnClick="incrementGist()"></p>
```

If I actually hit the button, the error I get is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

But if I subsequently open the console and run this:

```
var crap = JSON.parse(gistData.response);
```

it works just fine. This happens in both Firefox and Chrome. I really don't see why the `JSON.parse` command fails inside a function call, but not in the console. An actual page is set up [here](http://rmflight.github.io/staticReader/indexTest.html)

Comment: I'd log `gistData.response` as well, and if it's an empty string, then that is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Classic case of trying to make an asynchronous call act like a synchronous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to read the response before the server answered.

You must read the response in a callback. For example :

```
gistData = createCORSRequest('GET', gistQuery);
gistData.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (gistData.readyState === 4) {
    if (gistData.status === 200) {
                 tmpJSON = JSON.parse(gistData.response);
                 ... use tmpJSON...
                 ... which should not be called so as it is not JSON...
                 ... maybe tmpObject ?
            }
    }
}
gistData.send();
```

Comment: yeah well that's exactly it :)

Comment: That worked great, thank you. I've never worked with network data like this, I just assumed that the function would wait until the response was done. Good to know.

Comment: The A in AJAX stands for asynchronous. Many patterns in Javascript, like AJAX, make you deal with asynchronous operations and thus with callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not waiting the request to actually finish. I don't know your API but try waiting the server response then parse your JSON. you could try with a SetTimeout first to see that it is working but you nee to do something like in jQuery with its' `success:function(...)` callback